How to change boot order in systemd (PopOS) UEFI?
I habe Windows 10 on one partition, PopOS 22.04 on another. I managed to get them working with the systemd boot manager. How can I change the boot order in the boot menu? (I want Windows to be first, all the Linux options after that.)
user1@pop-os:~$ sudo bootctl list
Boot Loader Entries:
        title: Pop!_OS
           id: Pop_OS-current.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf
        linux: /EFI/Pop_OS-a3c80fd2-d6ad-439a-b994-5ae585aafd18/vmlinuz.efi
       initrd: /EFI/Pop_OS-a3c80fd2-d6ad-439a-b994-5ae585aafd18/initrd.img
      options: root=UUID=a3c80fd2-d6ad-439a-b994-5ae585aafd18 ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash

        title: Pop!_OS recovery
           id: Recovery-7E2F-1964.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/Recovery-7E2F-1964.conf
        linux: /EFI/Recovery-7E2F-1964/vmlinuz.efi
       initrd: /EFI/Recovery-7E2F-1964/initrd.gz
      options: boot=casper hostname=recovery userfullname=Recovery username=recovery live-media-path=/casper-7E2F-1964 live-media=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/4bad88a4-3490-4b99-8765-5db6490f0443 noprompt

        title: Windows 10 (default)
           id: 1windows.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/1windows.conf

        title: Reboot Into Firmware Interface
           id: auto-reboot-to-firmware-setup
       source: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/LoaderEntries-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f


Does POPos have efibootmgr? https://askubuntu.com/questions/485261/change-boot-order-using-efibootmgr or man efibootmgr and its -o paramter. You always should be able to go into UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu) and in UEFI settings & boot tab change boot order.
